# What is the peak in fitness landscape

Tags: algorithms, heuristics

I have just started reading about fitness landscapes and I couldn't understand what the peak means. What does the peak mean?

Answer (score 2):

It's just the ordinary English-language meaning of the word:

> **peak**, n.
>   [...]
>   4 a (1) : the top of a hill or mountain ending in a point
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peak)</sub>

See, for example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_landscape):

> Fitness landscapes are often conceived of as ranges of mountains. There exist local peaks (points from which all paths are downhill, i.e. to lower fitness) and valleys (regions from which many paths lead uphill).

Comment: Does that mean the peak is a solution to the problem?

Comment: Depending on context, it may be _a_ solution. But the best solution is Mount Everest; you might be standing on top of some other mountain and you gotta go back down before you can get there.